# How do I run my code when I have my modules folder, packagejson and webpackconfig?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, server

I need help with my code I don't know why, when I run "start" on my code from webpack and open the serve with node.js I get a "Cannot GET" from Chrome, my TS code it's correct and I do the steps of webpack-page "correct" (if I do something wrong I don't see it).`

github.com/Lien0/modulos

I need a hero!! I will be very grateful if you help me.